# Vue Nuxt Routes, how to make it simplier

Tags: vue.js, routes, frontend, nuxt.js, vue-router

could someone tell me, how to make only 3 rules for this? Routes list of articles and list of all articles are 2x here, because of pagination, is there a way how to make it by 1 rule?

And is there any chance to make it all by just one rule?

```
{
  /**
   * PostType paths
   */
  // list of articles for category with pagination
  {
    path: '/posttype/category/:path+/page/:page(\\d+)/',
    component: () => interopDefault(import('~/pages/archive/Category.vue')),
    name: 'term-category_article-paged',
    meta: { taxonomy: 'category' },
    pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true }
  },
  // same as list of articles for category but only first page
  {
    path: '/posttype/category/:path+/',
    component: () => interopDefault(import('~/pages/archive/Category.vue')),
    name: 'term-category_article',
    meta: { taxonomy: 'category' },
    pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true }
  },
  // list of all articles for post type with pagination
  {
    path: '/posttype/page/:page(\\d+)/',
    component: () => interopDefault(import('~/pages/archive/Archive.vue')),
    name: 'archive-article',
    meta: {},
    pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true }
  },
  // same as list of all articles for post type but only first page
  {
    path: '/posttype/',
    component: () => interopDefault(import('~/pages/frontpage/Archive.vue')),
    name: 'frontpage-article',
    pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true }
  },
  // detail of article
  {
    path: '/posttype/:slug/',
    component: () => interopDefault(import('~/pages/single/Article.vue')),
    name: 'single-article',
    props: route => ({
      slug: route.params.slug
    }),
    pathToRegexpOptions: { strict: true }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use file based routing? This is by far the simplest. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing

Comment: Also, the pagination maybe don't need a specific route. You could check the entered number and fetch the required range of data regarding the number directly.

Comment: I can't use file base routing, because I need to have highly customised routes.

I don't know how you mean second comment... i want to have less routes, that's why I ask how.

Comment: This package is not enough? https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module I find that it gives a lot of flexibility for a lot of things directly embedded into the components. Can you give us a schema of the routes that you do have actually? (an example to understand better your regexes)